# Wix XmlFile: Fails to uninstall when XPath attributes are used in ElementPath

Tags: xml, xpath, wix, visual-studio-2013, uninstallation

I am trying to remove entries from an XML file during uninstall.

This is the code in question:

```
<util:XmlFile Id='XmlSettings1' File='[InstallDir]Station.config' Action='createElement' Name='Control' ElementPath='//StationConfig/ControlManager/Controls' Sequence='1' />
<util:XmlFile Id='XmlSettings2' File='[InstallDir]Station.config' Action='setValue' Name='name' Value='Fusion' ElementPath="//StationConfig/ControlManager/Controls/Control[\[]not(@name)[\]]" Sequence='2' />
<util:XmlFile Id='XmlSettings3' File='[InstallDir]Station.config' Action='setValue' Name='enable' Value='true' ElementPath="//StationConfig/ControlManager/Controls/Control[\[]@name='Fusion'[\]]" Sequence='3' />
```

The failure reads:

> Failed to find node: //StationConfig/ControlManager/Controls/control[not(@name)] in XML file: C:\InstallDir\Station.config, system error: -2147020584

My guess is that it's trying to back out the changes starting from Sequence 3, but when it gets to #2 it doesn't know what to do with the [not(@name)] and throws its hands up.

Is there a way to tell it to just jump straight to Sequence #1 and delete the whole element during uninstall?

Comment: Have you tried reauthoring your code with the XmlConfig element? It has an attribute called "On" in which you can specify whether to make the changes on installation or uninstallation.
See http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/xmlconfig.html